# Identifier Expected error on 2D Collision Code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I am trying to make a oncollision2D EnemyDamage is done removing health from playerStats.health, unfortunately I got the error, "Identifier expected" does anyone know what I need to put there to get the code to work? Thanks error on Collision (8,41). 
Collision damage code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Collision : MonoBehaviour {

 int EnemyDamage = 1;

     void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) 
 {
     playerStats.Health -= EnemyDamage;
 }
}
```

Player Health Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

 [System.Serializable]
 public class PlayerStats {
     public int Health = 100;
 }

 public PlayerStats playerStats = new PlayerStats();

 public int fallBoundary = -20;

 void Update () {
     if (transform.position.y <= fallBoundary)
         DamagePlayer (9999999);
 }

 public void DamagePlayer (int damage) {
     playerStats.Health -= damage;
     if (playerStats.Health <= 0) {
         GameMaster.KillPlayer(this);
     }
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you put down what you have tried, as well as the full error with the stack track? -- have you looked at the exception or the inner exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collision2D` is a class and is used to return collision information when used with the `OnCollisionEnter2D` callback function. If you are going to use it, you have to put a variable after it.

```
  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) 
  {

  }
```

should be

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    playerStats.Health -= EnemyDamage;
}
```

If you don't need to get information about the collison, you can just use the `OnCollisionEnter2D` function without `Collision2D` parameter at-all.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D()
{
    playerStats.Health -= EnemyDamage;
}
```